# How can I connect a jQuery slideshow with a database in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

So I'm using a jQuery plug-in called Coin Slider. The slideshow seems to be working fine but I want to connect it with a database that I have created in the App_Date folder in Visual Studio 2010.

When clicked on a certain picture, I want the system to search the table in the database using the description of that particular image in the slideshow as a keyword. If the item exists in the database, it would go to the website mentioned in the href. Otherwise, it would display "item not found".

All I've done is make the slideshow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="css/coin-slider/coin-slider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/coin-slider/coin-slider-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#coin-slider').coinslider();
        });
</script>




</head>
<body>
<div id='coin-slider'>
    <a href="the first website goes here" target="_blank">
        <img src='1.jpg' >
        <span>
            Description goes here
        </span>
    </a>
    <a href="the second website goes here">
        <img src='2.jpg' >
        <span>
            Description goes here
        </span>
    </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a tutorial site

Comment: So far so good. Now try connecting you DB, get some data, send a query or two and if it doesn't work, come back and ask us to help.